# Как запустить команды (одну за одной) для mongodb в windows (создать правильно bat или скрипт)

Tags: mongodb, bat

Допустим присутствуют  команды :

```
use users

db.createUser({user:"admin", pwd:"1234",roles:["readWrite","dbAdmin"]})

db.users.insert({"name": "Tom", "age": 28, languages: ["english", 
"spanish"]})

db.users.find()

db.users.find().pretty()
```

И так далее...

Как правильно написать bat или что-то другое чтобы mongo.exe их все последовательно выполнил?
Хотелось бы получить вывод всех команд , то есть результаты запросов